# VBA - Screen updating not working as expected

Tags: vba, excel

I have protected workbook, where the user is allowed to make changes only on certain fields. Since we cannot control the copy/paste format from the user end. I have the below code that will help me to keep the destination formatting.

I have the workbook formatted with Font 'Calibri'. So if the user copies the data onto workbook from any other format, it helps me in retaining the 'Calibri' Font.

My concern: When user copies data, for a second it shows the source formatting before the code gets activated and changes the format I need. I have Turned screen updating off to speed up your macro code. But it is serving my purpose. Is it possible to eliminate this issue?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim vNewValues As Variant
        NewValues = Target
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo

        Target = NewValues

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried to update the code as below. `.Undo` function is creating a problem

```
  Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim vNewValues As Variant
        NewValues = Target
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        Target.Font.Size = 11
        Target.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Target.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Target.WrapText = True
        Application.Undo
        Target = NewValues
   End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps a more light-weight event handler that directly sets the font (and other relevant formats) of `Target` without bothering with `ScreenUpdating` or `EnableEvents` might reduce or even eliminate the problem. This code seems like overkill for the stated problem.

Comment: The lines `NewValues = Target`, `Application.Undo` and `Target = NewValues` should simply be dropped if you go this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @John Coleman suggested you only need this code in the sheet for which you want to keep the fonts calibri,

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Target.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    End Sub
```

If you want this for all the sheets in the workbook then paste this code in your workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Font.Name = "Calibri"
End Sub
```

@Sady , This is your updated code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        Target.Font.Size = 11
        Target.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        Target.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Target.WrapText = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if you use this `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` event then no need to paste code in each sheet

Comment: @Maddy True but I'm not sure if sady wants this for all the sheets !

Comment: @ImranMalek, thank you for your reply. Yes, I would need this for all the sheets. So, you mean I have to input all the formats I need in the code directly.

Comment: @sady Yes you can set all other formats in the second code in that case.

Comment: @ImranMalek, Would you please suggest me how do I manipulate the code to append the format I need? I tried to update the code(updated in question) but I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: @sady You don't need undo part from your update.Check the code I have updated in the answer.